# WordPress User Count

Tags: php, wordpress

How would you subtract 1 from the WordPress user count so that a hidden Administrator user does not get counted?

I can hide the count all together but I would rather just subtract 1 from the count.

https://snipboard.io/CfAIcG.jpg

Inserting code into Functions.php

Comment: how to you know that an administrator is hidden ? are you using custom function for that already ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why you want to hide count but the actual hidden administrator profile on users page.

I have done the subtract count as you wanted. Put the this code in functions.php and visit users page.

```
add_filter("views_users", 'editCounts', 10, 1);
function editCounts($views) {
    if ( current_user_can( 'administrator' ) ) {
        $total = count_users();
        $newTotal = $total['total_users']-1;
        $views = array('all' => '<a href="users.php" class="current" aria-current="page">All <span class="count">('.$newTotal.')</span></a>', 'administrator' => '<a href="users.php?role=administrator">Administrator <span class="count">('.$newTotal.')</span></a>');
        return $views;
    }else{
        return $views;
    }
}
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Thank You! You are awesome! It works perfectly!